# Error: Java Null and String Input exception

Tags: java, string, exception, nullpointerexception, try-catch

So I want to do a validation check where I check if the input box is null and if it has an invalid prameter such as string in Java. However this code is not working, it says that it is undefined for the argumnet types. userid is a double and I want to check if the inout box is empty. Also I want to check through the try catch block if there is any invalid data added (such as string). The input box does not have any validation for test purposes.

```
if (userid != null);
catch (Exception e)   {  
logger.warn("Add data", e);
}
```

Comment: double is a primitive and primitives cannot be null in java.

Comment: You haven't given *any* code about the input box, and if the type of `userid` is `double`, then it can't have a `null` value. You can't catch an exception without a `try` block, and your `if` statement doesn't actually do anything (you've just got an empty statement as the body). It's really hard to know what you're expecting here..

Comment: How about showing the relevant code, and the complete and exact error message?

Comment: Your code example is strange. You should probably read a tutorial.

Comment: what action have you taken if the code input is null ? I dont see any handling for null here

Answer (score 1):

`double` is a primitive type and can never be `null` in Java. If you want to check for `null`, use `Double`, which is the wrapped type.

It's hard to tell what your code is doing here. You have an `if` with an empty body and so it is effectively doing nothing. Also, where do you expect an exception to be thrown? Finally you shouldn't be catching `Exception`. Pokemon-style exception-handling is a sign that you're not handling your exceptions properly.